# how to import google fusion tables into mysql to draw a polygon on google map?

Tags: php, mysql, regex, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

have this [csv file](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1jgWYtlqGSPzlIa-is8wl1cZkVIWEm_89rWUwqFU) and I wish to import it in my MySQL database to draw all polygons I want simply by typing a postcode.
In this file I have

- the postcode
- a list of coordinates (my idea is to use all coordinates to draw an accurate polygon
- a field called 'area' (I have no idea how to use this information)

My first problem is how to parse this file to save data in my DB to have 3 columns

```
|postcode|latitude|longitude
```

Can you help with this issue please? Or suggest me a better way if you know.

Thanks.

**Edit:** I am trying to use this php code editing each time the string

```
$fname = "uk.csv";
$fhandle = fopen($fname,"r");
$content = fread($fhandle,filesize($fname));

$content = str_replace('"<MultiGeometry><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>', '', $content);

$fhandle = fopen($fname,"w");
fwrite($fhandle,$content);
fclose($fhandle);
```

but this file is homogeneous because not all rows start with the same string

```
<MultiGeometry><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>
```

but also with only

```
<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't only a string, it's valid XML.

Use  DOM-methods to parse the String.

simple example:

```
  //create DOMDocument
$doc=new DOMDocument();
  //load the source from string
$doc->loadXML('<MultiGeometry><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>0.167014,51.79976,0.0 0.167634,51.79976,0.0 0.177091,51.796733,0.0 0.181105,51.793738,0.0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></MultiGeometry>');
  //fetch the coordinates-nodes
$coords=$doc->getElementsByTagName('coordinates');
  //get the content of the first <coordinates/>
echo $coords->item(0)->nodeValue;
  //returns:
  //0.167014,51.79976,0.0 0.167634,51.79976,0.0 0.177091,51.796733,0.0 0.181105,51.793738,0.0
```

Comment: thank you for your answer @Dr.Molle but the problem is not all rows start with 'MultiGeometry' tag: some rows start with 'Poligon' instead of 'MultiGeometry

Comment: It doesn't matter how it starts , the example accesses the `<coordinates/>`-nodes directly

Comment: I'm not being able to correctly parse the file. I have this file called 'uk.csv'. I tried to put it in loadXML() but it dosn't works. My intention is to parse the file to have, such as in my initial post, a table of this type

|postcode|latitude|longitude

foreach postcode, obviously, I can have more couple of lat/lng

Comment: The file contains CSV, use `fgetcsv` to extract the columns out of the lines. And of course you have multiple LatLng's, Polygons are defined by multiple points. How do you expect to be able to draw a polygon by a single point?

Comment: I know to draw a polygon many point are required: this is my reason for that I wish to extract all coordinates (lat/long) foreach postcode and save all in DB in way to have, forearch postcode, many coordinates to draw a polygon foreach postcode.
I try to use fgetcsv

Comment: I don't understand why you don't consider using the FusionTable directly, like [this](http://geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTables_UKpostcode_map.html) (which uses GVis) or a FusionTablesLayer directly.